# How to put searchable in NSPopover?

Tags: macos, swiftui, nspopover, searchable

So I have the following `ContentView` shows as a popover in the menu bar.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Create the SwiftUI view that provides the window contents.
    let contentView = ContentView()

    // Create the popover
    let popover = NSPopover()
    popover.contentSize = NSSize(width: 500, height: 700)
    popover.behavior = .transient
    popover.contentViewController = NSHostingController(rootView: contentView)
    self.popover = popover
    
    // Create the status item
    self.statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: CGFloat(NSStatusItem.variableLength))
    
    if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
        button.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("Icon"))
        button.action = #selector(togglePopover(_:))
    }
    (NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).statusBarItem.button?.image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("Icon"))


    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
}

@objc func togglePopover(_ sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let button = self.statusBarItem.button {
        if self.popover.isShown {
            self.popover.performClose(sender)
        } else {
            self.popover.show(relativeTo: button.bounds, of: button, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
        }
        self.popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.becomeKey()
    }
    
    self.popover.contentViewController?.view.window?.becomeKey()
}
```

And my content view has a `.searchable()` tag. I see it when loading it under normal window but not when loading it under a popover. Does anyone know how can I adapt the searchable to the pop over?

Comment: [The `searchable` modifier must be placed on or inside a `NavigationView`, `NavigationStack`, or `NavigationSplitView`.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/adding-search-to-your-app) Does your `ContentView` do that?

Comment: Yes, my contenview's body has a NavigationStack and the searchable is inside the NavigationStack tag :/